# SolrCloud is always starting in Example. Solr Home configuration is not working

Tags: solr, solrcloud

Solr Cloud always starts in example and configuration specified in solr.in.sh is not working. 
What are changes required to start with custom configuration ?

I have setup Zookeeper in ensemble mode and also do changes in solr.in.sh. But, it seems Solr is always starts with Example

Comment: The configuration and available collections are loaded from Zookeeper when in cloud mode - my guess is that the example collection already exists there?

Comment: Problem resolved. I was executing with -e option, hence other configuration was not working. I know its silly mistake. Im still learning Solr

Answer (score 0):

I saw your answer in comments, yet completing the answer for others.

- To start solr in cloud mode you need to add "-cloud":-  solr start -cloud
- -e start in interactive mode with one example. This is just for newbies to get started with solrcloud